# C++ CMake Compile directives versus?

Tags: c++, cmake, architecture

I am currently building big projects containing several subprojects (of subprojects (of ...)). Each subprojects can have compiler directives. If the compiler directive is at the lowest level of subprojects, compiler directives are then passed to each level above the subproject at the lowest level with resulting in a lot of projects at the end.

**First question:** is it a good practice? What might be the alternatives?

**Second question:** Would be a good practice to pass the compiler directive at the top level (i.e. MyApp)? The application will have members passed to constructor of subprojects with option parameters...

For example I have an application (MyApp) with a subproject (network). The lowest subproject (network) contains all the network modules and methods with a compiler directive *IPV6*. At the end I have four projects called:

- MyApp with network
- MyApp_IPV6 with network_IPV6

Now I let you imagine with several subprojects at different levels and different compiler directives...

**edit:**
By compiler directives I mean compile definitions as:

```
#ifdef IPV6
// do stuff
#endif
```

Comment: What do you mean by "compiler directive"?

Comment: I mean compile definitions to build some code lines for some projects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CMake you would do that using target properties:

```
add_executable(MyApp ...)
add_executable(MyApp_IPV6 ...)

add_subdirectory(network)

# consumes the public interface of network
target_link_libraries(MyApp PRIVATE network)

# consumes the public interface of network_IPV6
target_link_libraries(MyApp_IPV6 PRIVATE network_IPV6)
```

Then in the CMake file inside `network/`, add your target and its compile definition:

```
add_library(network STATIC files...)
add_library(network_IPV6 STATIC files...)

# add IPV6 into its interface
target_compile_definitions(network_IPV6 PUBLIC IPV6)
```

Because the target `network_IPV6` is setting the definition as `IPV6`, anyone that link to it will have that definition too.

---

Another solution could be to build everything only one time by configuration and let the user decide if he wants ipv6 or not.

It would work like this:

```
option(MYAPP_USE_IPV6 "Compile MyApp with ipv6 support", OFF)
add_subdirectory(network)

# consumes the public interface of network
target_link_libraries(MyApp PRIVATE network)
```

Then, inside the network directory:

```
add_library(network STATIC files...)

if (MYAPP_USE_IPV6)
    # add IPV6 into its interface
    target_compile_definitions(network_IPV6 PUBLIC IPV6)
endif()
```

You then configure your app as needed, or configure both profiles:

```
mkdir build
mkdir build-ipv6

cd build
cmake ..

cd ../build-ipv6
cmake .. -DMYAPP_USE_IPV6=ON
```

Comment: thanks you for this full answer. With your example, my IDE will still have as many libraries and/or exes as compilation definitions?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. It will if you IDE is showing a list of compiler definitions? In the first example, you have four target to usually IDEs will show these four. With the second example, the IDE will only show two targets, but will show two available configurations for your project. This is how VSCode, VS and KDevelop work. I haven't used other IDEs enough to tell.